# What is the difference between list[i] vs list.ToList()[i] in C#?

Tags: c#

I am coming back to `C#` after a long time. Usually, when I want to get or set some value at a specific index, I use `.list[i]` but recently I have noticed `.list.ToList()[i]` pattern.

**Question:**

What is the difference OR advantage of that?

**Code:**

```
var randomWords = new List<string>{ "abc", "def", "ghi"};

for (int i = 0; i < randomWords.Count; i++)
{
  Console.WriteLine(randomWords[i]); 
  Console.WriteLine(randomWords.ToList()[i]);
}
```

**Output:**

```
abc
abc
def
def
ghi
ghi
```

Comment: `ToList` will create a shallow copy of the list, however as you're accessing just a single item there's absolutely no use in that. This is just bursting memory and performance.

Comment: If you really found that kind of code often enough in a code base to constitute a pattern then you should initiate a serious talk about that.

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride good point. I have a very simple logic which iterate through the list. This list might have 20 to 25 indexed, at max. In this case I believe `.list[i]` is ideal candidate. But I wanted to clear my doubt first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ToList()` is a Linq extension method that will create a `List<T>` from any `IEnumerable<T>`, such as arrays, lists, or even a query that needs to be executed.

If you call it on something that's already a `List<T>`, it will create a copy of that list and get the `i`th element, which is not functionally different other than you're working with a shallow copy of the list.

Without knowing what `.list` is it's hard to know why someone would do that - perhaps `.list` is a poorly named property of a type that does not have an indexed, or a lazy-loaded query?

If `.list` is already a list or has an indexer, I see no benefit of creating another list just to call the indexer.

Even if `.list` did not have an indexer, there are more efficient ways to get the `i`th element without creating a list.

Comment: `.list` is already a list with indexer.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason that comes to my mind about calling `ToList` on an already materialized list is to create a (shallow) copy of it. So effectivly to create a readonly list. However be aware that while you can't alter the original *list*, you can of course manipulate the *items* in it via the new reference., e.g.

```
listCopy[3].MyProperty = "new value";
```

However you're accessing only a single item anyway, so you can't add or remove to the original list anyway.

All in all I'd argue that's only bursting memory as you're copying the entire list for the sake of nothing.